# Is there a performance difference between futures::executor::block_on and block_in_place

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have calls to async code inside a synchronous method (this method is part of a trait and I can't implement it asynchronously) so I use `block_on` to wait for the async calls to finish.

The sync method will be called from async code.

So the application is in `#[tokio::main]`  and it calls the synchronous method when some event happens (endpoint hit), and the synchronous method will call some async code and wait on it to finish and return.

Turns out `block_on` can't be used inside async code. I have found `tokio::task::block_in_place` kind of spawns a synchronous context inside the async context, thus allows one to call `block_on` inside it.

So the method now looks like this:

```rust
impl SomeTrait for MyStruct {
    fn some_sync_method(&self, handle: tokio::runtime::Handle) -> u32 {
        tokio::task::block_in_place(|| {
            handle.block_on(some_async_function())
        }
    }
}
```

Is this implementation better or using `futures::executor::block_on` instead:

```rust
impl SomeTrait for MyStruct {
    fn some_sync_method(&self, handle: tokio::runtime::Handle) -> u32 {
        futures::executor::block_on(some_async_function())
    }
}
```

What is the underlying difference between the two implementations and in which cases each of them would be more efficient.

Btw, this method gets called a lot. This is part of a web server.

Comment: Wait a second... If the sync code that blocks on async code gets called from async code... can't you just make *everything* async and instead of blocking, you just `.await`?

Comment: I can't make `some_sync_method` async because it's part of a trait from another library and it's sync.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `futures::executors::block_on()`. Even before comparing the performance, there is something more important to consider: `futures::executors::block_on()` is just wrong here, as it blocks the asynchronous runtime.

[As explained in `block_in_place()` docs](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.block_in_place.html):

> In general, issuing a blocking call or performing a lot of compute in a future without yielding is problematic, as it may prevent the executor from driving other tasks forward. Calling this function informs the executor that the currently executing task is about to block the thread, so the executor is able to hand off any other tasks it has to a new worker thread before that happens. See the [CPU-bound tasks and blocking code](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/index.html#cpu-bound-tasks-and-blocking-code) section for more information.

`futures::executors::block_on()` is likely to be a little more performant (I haven't benchmarked though) because it doesn't inform the executor. But that is the point: you *need* to inform the executor. Otherwise, your code can get stuck until your blocking function completes, performing essentially serializedly, without utilizing the device's resources.

If this code is most of the code, you may reconsider using an async runtime. It may be more efficient if you just spawn threads. Or just give up on using that library and use only async code.

Comment: Yeah I figured out that `futures::executor::block_on` does indeed deadlock when I tested my code that is using it with `#[tokio::test]` (which uses `current_thread` runtime and not `multi_thread`, but `block_in_place` requires `multi_thread`  runtime already).

I benchmarked both implementations using `#[tokio::test(flavor = "multi_thread")]`.
They give pretty bad performance when the number of async requests go high.
I think the solution I should go for now is having some `std::thread` pool do the work.