# Implementing Drop for a Future in Rust

Tags: rust, async-await, future, drop, pinning

I have an async function (let's call is `my_async_fn`) that should support cancellation (I want to allow the caller to use [tokio::time::timeout](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.23.0/tokio/time/fn.timeout.html) or [futures::future::select](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.25/futures/future/fn.select.html) with `my_async_fn`). I also need to perform some cleanup, regardless of whether `my_async_fn` was cancelled or not (I need to remove some contents in a file that `my_async_fn` writes).

So my approach was to write a future that forwards polling to an inner future and implements `Drop` by calling a provided `FnMut`:

```rust
trait OnDropFutureExt
where
    Self: Future + Sized,
{
    fn on_drop<D: FnMut()>(self, on_drop: D) -> OnDropFuture<Self, D>;
}
impl<F: Future> OnDropFutureExt for F {
    fn on_drop<D: FnMut()>(self, on_drop: D) -> OnDropFuture<Self, D> {
        OnDropFuture {
            inner: self,
            on_drop,
        }
    }
}


struct OnDropFuture<F: Future, D: FnMut()> {
    inner: F,
    on_drop: D,
}
impl<F: Future, D: FnMut()> OnDropFuture<F, D> {
    // See: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/#pinning-is-structural-for-field
    fn get_mut_inner(self: Pin<&mut Self>) -> Pin<&mut F> {
        unsafe { self.map_unchecked_mut(|s| &mut s.inner) }
    }

    // See: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/#pinning-is-not-structural-for-field
    fn get_mut_on_drop(self: Pin<&mut Self>) -> &mut D {
        unsafe { &mut self.get_unchecked_mut().on_drop }
    }
}
impl<F: Future, D: FnMut()> Future for OnDropFuture<F, D> {
    type Output = F::Output;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<F::Output> {
        self.get_mut_inner().poll(cx)
    }
}
impl<F: Future, D: FnMut()> Drop for OnDropFuture<F, D> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // See: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/#drop-implementation
        inner_drop(unsafe { Pin::new_unchecked(self) });
        fn inner_drop<F: Future, D: FnMut()>(this: Pin<&mut OnDropFuture<F, D>>) {
            this.get_mut_on_drop()();
        }
    }
}
```

This allows me to call `my_async_fn` like this:

```rust
my_async_fn().on_drop(|| clean_up_file(&file_path)).await?;
```

Now I have a few questions:

1. Since I can't propagate an error from `clean_up_file` I guess the best I can do is to just log if I failed to clean up the file and continue. Or is there a better option?
2. In https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/#pinning-is-structural-for-field it sais:

> You must make sure that you uphold the Drop guarantee: once your struct is pinned, the memory that contains the content is not overwritten or deallocated without calling the content’s destructors. This can be tricky, as witnessed by VecDeque: the destructor of VecDeque can fail to call drop on all elements if one of the destructors panics. This violates the Drop guarantee, because it can lead to elements being deallocated without their destructor being called. (VecDeque has no pinning projections, so this does not cause unsoundness.)

My future does have a pinning projection for the `inner` future, so do I have to make sure that `on_drop` never panics? Should I add something like `std::panic::catch_unwind`? How would I do that, since mutable references are not `UnwindSafe`?

3. Since drop is a sync function I would implement `clean_up_file` as a sync function as well. It shouldn't block to long to clean up the file, so that shouldn't be a problem, right? Or is it better to use [futures::executor::block_on](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.25/futures/executor/fn.block_on.html)? Would that not block the current thread and allow other tasks to run while waiting for the file to get cleaned up?
4. Ideally I would want `on_drop` to be a `FnOnce()`, since it is only called once anyways. Is it safe to change the type of `on_drop` to `ManuallyDrop<D>` and implement `Drop` like this:

```rust
impl<F: Future, D: FnOnce()> Drop for OnDropFuture<F, D> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // See: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/#drop-implementation
        inner_drop(unsafe { Pin::new_unchecked(self) });
        fn inner_drop<F: Future, D: FnOnce()>(this: Pin<&mut OnDropFuture<F, D>>) {
            let on_drop = unsafe { ManuallyDrop::take(this.get_mut_on_drop()) };
            on_drop()
        }
    }
}
```

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/74914046/4149050 this should be safe right?

Comment: You might want to checkout [`tempfile`](https://docs.rs/tempfile/latest/tempfile/#) which is a tried and tested way of accomplishing exactly what you want here.

Comment: Well I guess I lied when I said that I just need to delete the file, I actually need to modify it to delete some of it's contents. I will update the question. Tempfile is a great suggestion though if i actually needed to delete the file!

Comment: Maybe I can restructure the code so I only need to delete files instead of modifying them at the end. I will look into that, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: That also gives me another idea: I could just create a custom struct at the beginning of the `async` function and have it's `Drop` implementation do the cleanup.

Comment: Recommendation: use `pin-project` or `pin-project-lite`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since I can't propagate an error from `clean_up_file` I guess the best I can do is to just log if I failed to clean up the file and continue. Or is there a better option?

Yes. Errors on `Drop` are problematic. For the error case, this is all you can do (if you don't want to panic). For the success case, provide a `fn cleanup(self)` method on the future that returns `Result` and should be called manually so you can handle the error (it should prevent running `Drop` of course).

> My future does have a pinning projection for the `inner` future, so do I have to make sure that `on_drop` never panics? Should I add something like `std::panic::catch_unwind`?

No. `VecDeque` drops all elements itself, so an error can prevent it from dropping elements. But you are using the drop glue generated by the compiler. If `on_drop` will panic, the compiler will still run the drop glue for `inner`. Even if `on_drop` would be declared on the struct before `inner`, causing it to drop first, panicking on it then panicking on its destructor (a double panic) would not be a problem, as it would cause a hard abort.

> Since drop is a sync function I would implement `clean_up_file` as a sync function as well. It shouldn't block to long to clean up the file, so that shouldn't be a problem, right? Or is it better to use `futures::executor::block_on`? Would that not block the current thread and allow other tasks to run while waiting for the file to get cleaned up?

Ideally, it would be an async function, but [async drop](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-fundamentals-initiative/roadmap/async_drop.html) is still not available (and it is questionable whether it ever will), so it must be sync.

> Ideally I would want `on_drop` to be a `FnOnce()`, since it is only called once anyways. Is it safe to change the type of `on_drop` to `ManuallyDrop<D>` and implement `Drop` like this:

Yes.

Comment: Would `futures::executor::block_on` make sence in the drop implementation? If I understand correctly it would still block the caller in the same way, but it would allow deleting and modifying files in drop concurrently, right? I saw your answer about `tokio::task::block_in_place`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73273820/4149050 but that would require all users of my library to use the tokio runtime, right? If someone where using a different runtime it wouldn't work, would it?

Comment: @Adrodoc Yes, it will enable this to be concurrent. It is better to use `tokio`'s `tokio::task::block_in_place()`, but if you're blocking for a short time... and especially on the error case... I think this is fine.